# Do new users have a harder time now earning rep than they did 8 years ago?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, old-questions, stack-exchange

Been flipping through new questions for a while, modestly answering questions I know a bit about (mostly winforms or string manipulation, the easy stuff) and collecting my +10 or +15 for the ones I get to before anyone else can. Rarely ever will I post a question at this stage as I've learned early on that 99% of the time my question will have already been asked. So I try to avoid that awful awful feeling of getting 3 or 4 down-votes and a fat "[DUPLICATE]" mark on my question and just spend the extra time searching instead.

This is fine and ultimately I'm learning and developing and all that, but having stumbled into some big league guys like Cody Gray or other users with 100k+ rep it makes me wonder how they got up there. I've been on here for ~5 months now and I've only got ~500 rep to show for it. How on earth is one to achieve 100k+?

I discussed it with some friends (also young, new users of SO and other SE sites) and it came up that all the "obvious" questions seem to be gone now. Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-commits-in-git) as an example. This is a great example of a super easy question most people could probably answer today, however no one can ever ask it again. As a result I feel a lot of the super easy questions have been "used up" so we're left with only obscure, niche questions that at most see maybe 3-4 up-votes. Anecdotally I can say (though I must admit I pretty much only browse `c#` so my reference may be skewed) I've never seen a new post go to anything over 5 up-votes in a day or two (I often check back on the ones I like).

Just another point to be made, I recently posted [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321476/why-dont-we-use-low-voltage-power-sources-for-high-wattage-applications) over at Electrical Engineering SE. Anyone here who's got a bit of background in electronics will know this is a pretty dumb question. I mean, I almost didn't want to post it I was so embarrassed about asking it. But it got 28. Freaking. Up-votes. That's insane! That's my best question yet!

I think the above is a really good example of how different rep works on young stack exchange sites vs older ones (like SO). So **FINALLY** my question is, why is the rep system for new SOers so difficult to climb? Am I doing it wrong? Would you agree that when SO was young, it was easier to earn rep?

I'm not sure if this is the place for this but I just wanted to give back some feedback I've come up with after having used the site for a while now. Let me know if anything in my post is wrong.

Comment: I don't have 200k. :-( Anyway, while it is true that the users who have been around a while tend to have lots of reputation, that's more because it's trickled in over time rather than because we answered a bunch of easy questions. It don't think it was that much easier to earn rep back in the old days than it is now. Plus, there are also *still* plenty of easily-answerable questions asked here every day. Languages and tools change all the time, and there are endless permutations on a theme that need specialized answers. It just takes persistence. Hang in there!

Comment: I don't have that experience you are describing. I gave a few good answers (even for some trivia), and my rep has grown quite quickly.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm about to put a big fat "[DUPLICATE]" mark on your question. Please don't take it personally. You should not feel awful when your question is marked as a duplicate. You didn't do anything wrong here. It just turns out that we've been at this so long, sometimes it seems just about every discussion that can be had has been had before.

Comment: @CodyGray Holy crap it's you. Edited to fix that about the 200k, my bad. I thought about what you said after posting actually lol. I guess it's because the stuff I'm getting into is pretty old stuff that's why I feel it's so saturated? Maybe if I got super involved with Angular or NodeJS apps or something hot right now I could ask more "super easy" questions.

Comment: @CodyGray ah okay : ( thanks for the feedback though

Comment: @CodyGray If you're asking questions easily answered by some simple research then you *are* doing something wrong.  That the OP has decided to spend more time searching for answers before asking, instead of just asking without doing any/much research, means that they *were* doing something wrong, and the site's tools *correctly* addressed it, and resulted in the desired behavior (more searching before asking).

Comment: @Servy Without getting too deep into complaints about some people being "dupe-marking trigger happy" sometimes your situation might be different in a couple little ways that make existing questions on the topic not so helpful. Also about doing research, I think we're pretty good at filtering out people who don't do it themselves these days, but look at that question about GIT I linked. There's no way undoing a commit has never been discussed before on the internet. Even if it was 8 years ago. Where's the "go do the research yourself" attitude there?

Comment: @CapnJack I *wouldn't* say that we're great at filtering out questions that are poorly researched.  The example you linked is a great example of it.  The fact that many people *don't* consider whether a post was well researched is indeed a serious problem I frequently run into (even though there certainly are cases where people clearly do take it into consideration).  There were plenty of posts from back then that *did* have votes indicating a lack of research, and there are plenty of posts asked to day that *don't* get downvotes despite being very poorly researched.

Comment: @Servy maybe not as good as we could be but definitely better I'd say. I want to also add thought that there is a significant difference in learning from researching and following tutorials or documentation vs having someone hold your hand and show you the ways. Definitely each have their own pros/cons but ultimately different people learn in different ways and I think there's value to getting a personal interaction over a problem instead of navigating the web finding something slightly relevant hoping it solves your problem.

Comment: @Servy Over on electrical engineering I was so thankful that those guys could give me answers at a level I could comprehend and the proceeded to answer all the new questions that sprang up from my newfound knowledge. Could I have found the answer myself googling it? Probably. But ultimately I came away with a lot more knowledge having been through a few discussions with the users and learning from them.

Comment: @CapnJack And SO isn't a private tutoring site.  It's specifically designed to *not* be one, and to be a place that creates useful artifacts for people to find and get a solution to their problem *without* needing to ask their own question to get the answer.  I agree, lots of people learn much better with a private tutor over doing research on their own, but that doesn't mean that that's what SO is here to do.

Comment: @Servy totally true. That's why I'm pretty quick to jump on questions like "My code is not work. plz fix" and tell them they need to show what they've tried/researched and then I'd be willing to help. I think it's a balance between the two that's most important here.

Comment: @CapnJack Side note: if you look at [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) profile for example you'll notice that he does not do orders of magnitude better than you - he get about 28 point per answer and you about 10... So if you simply provide as many answers you'll easily be in top-of-the top 50 SO users. Posting 33K reasonable answers *may take some time*, but...

Comment: Also, keep in mind some tags get more traffic than others. That's why the Unsung Hero badge exists.